# Serde JSON from Struct Example Not Working

Tags: rust, serde

I can't seem to get the provided [example](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/#creating-json-by-serializing-data-structures) of serializing a struct with serde to work. I'm implementing the trait `Serialize` for my `Address` struct, but I get a compile error that this trait is not implemented. What am I doing wrong?

```
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.118"
serde_json = "1.0.60"
```

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::Result;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Address {
    street: String,
    city: String,
}
fn main(){
    print_an_address();
}

fn print_an_address() -> Result<()> {
    // Some data structure.
    let address = Address {
        street: "10 Downing Street".to_owned(),
        city: "London".to_owned(),
    };

    // Serialize it to a JSON string.
    let j = serde_json::to_string(&address)?;

    // Print, write to a file, or send to an HTTP server.
    println!("{}", j);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Address: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:21:35
     |
21   |     let j = serde_json::to_string(&address)?;
     |                                   ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `Address`
     | 
    ::: C:\Users\Primary User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\serde_json-1.0.60\src\ser.rs:2221:17
     |
2221 |     T: ?Sized + Serialize,
     |                 --------- required by this bound in `serde_json::to_string`
```

Comment: [Your example works as-is.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d80818614a8fc859ad61ab7e02b2304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `derive` feature for `serde` in `Cargo.toml`.

```
serde = { version = "1.0.118", features = ["derive"] }
```

See this for more info: https://serde.rs/derive.html